# How to query ASP.NET Web API like OData, but with a POSTed JSON object, not a GET URL/QueryString?

Tags: json, linq, asp.net-web-api, odata

How to query ASP.NET Web API, but with a JSON POST, not GET URL?

The JSON object would contain the same data/filters/sort/paging as ODATA query or LINQ query. Can we deserialize the JSON object into something ODATA/LINQ can understand and then use that to easily execute on the DB (SQL Server)?

We've come across from articles about LINQ Expression Trees and ODataLib ODataUriParser, but still researching.

We want to expose an advanced search web service for a few tables or views in SQL Server, and want to keep it JSON and generic so many platforms can consume it. The consumer would need to pass in the search parameters, and we could probably create a data structure to contain it all, but are trying to also see if we can leverage some query model in ODATA or LINQ.

Any way to instead of putting the OData query in the URL, put it as a POSTed JSON object instead and have it continue to query the DB and return results normally? A couple of current reasons to put in POST are 1. can handle larger size and 2. instead of the consumer learning OData query syntax, they can just popular an search param object model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using `Asp-Net-Web-Api` I would advise to use the OData libraries. You can try using the `ODataController` to parse the OData query strings, this will append the correct monads to your `IQueryables`.

Comment: 2 to me is actually a HUGE down side. The OData query syntax is a) easy and b) standardized. Your query object is going to be non-standard and your clients will DEFINITELY need to learn your syntax. Your client might however have already learnt OData's syntax, or might be able to go online and download a library or tools (like LinqPad).